# Looking for one-liner to remove multiple sub-string

Tags: java, string

I have a string with contains two sub-strings:

```
sub_string1 = 123;
sub_string2 = 456;

full_string = "456".concat(sub_string1).concat(sub_string2);
```

Later I want to remove `sub_string1` and `sub_string2` from `full_string`.

My current method to do is cumbersome:

```
String Removed1 = full_string.replace(sub_string1, "");
String Removed2 = Removed1.replace(sub_string2, "");
```

I am looking for a one liner to solve this problem, any suggestions?

Comment: Probably too obvious to be the answer you need, but why not storing ans saving the original string for later. Then you simply revert back using the earlier stored string?

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to remove multiple occurence of string using Matches either token

```
String sub_string1 = "123";
String sub_string2 = "456";

String finals = "456df123".replaceAll(sub_string1 +"|"+sub_string2 , "");
//or
//String finals = "456df123".replaceAll("456|123" , "");
System.out.println(finals);
```

**result**:

```
df
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them like this:

```
String Removed = full_string.replace(sub_string1,"").replace(sub_string2, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is suffers from the problem that removal of the first substring could conceivably create appearances of the second that did not previously exist, and which would then be removed in the second step.  Any approach that performs the removals in two steps suffers from this issue.

If you want to remove only those appearances of the two substrings that appear in the *original* full string, then you have to perform both removals in one pass, and that is most easily accomplished with a regex-based approach.  It can be a bit tricky to construct such a regex if the substrings may contain regex metacharacters, but it can be done:

```
String removed = full_string.replace(
        Pattern.quote(substring1) + "|" + Pattern.quote(substring2), "");
```

I present it as a single *statement* spanning two lines, but the number of lines is simply a matter of whitespace.  If the number of source lines were really what you cared about then you could just concatenate the lines of your original code into one.

Note that the above still isn't necessarily perfect, in that it may or may not do what you want in the event that the tail of one substring matches the beginning of the other.